# Zero Padding a Matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a 5x20 Matrix, I intend to use Matrix Function and Transformations like Fourier Transform which can only be used for Symmetric Matrix. How can I convert the 5x20 Matrix to 20x20 Matrix by Zero Padding?

Comment: can you paste your matrix as text in the question? Also, can pandas & numpy be used in the solution?

Comment: suggest you to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/2970853) and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]])
b=np.zeros((20,20))

result = np.zeros_like(b)
x = 0
y = 0
result[x:a.shape[0],y:a.shape[1]] = a
print(result)
```

You can use the above logic to implement the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using numpy? If you do you can do it by slicing the arrays

```
import numpy as np

random_array_5_20 = np.random.rand(5, 20)

padded_array_20_20 = np.zeros((20, 20))

padded_array_20_20[:5, :20] = random_array_5_20
```

Answer (score 0):

One more approach.
Here `a` is the array that you already have.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(5,20)
za = np.zeros((1, 20))
while a.shape[0] < 20:
    a = np.concatenate((a,za))
```